# Where does the relation $H=1.66g_*\frac{1}{2} \frac{T^2}{M_P}=\frac{1}{2t}$ come from and what's the meaning of it?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, big-bang

I'm studying cosmology from my professor notes. At the moment, we're discussing the behaviour of the universe in terms of it being a gas made of relativistic and non-relativistic particles in thermal equilibrium and characterized by a certain number of degrees of freedom ($g$). As the contributions from bosons and fermions are not equal, one must take into account a factor $\frac{7}{8}$ when accounting for the fermions' degrees of freedom and we can write:

$$g_*(T)=\sum_{bosons}g_i\left( \frac{T_i}{T} \right)+\frac{7}{8}\sum_{fermions}g_i\left( \frac{T_i}{T} \right)$$

Where $g_i$ and $T_i$ refer to the number of degrees of freedom and the temperature of equilibrium of the particle $i$, and the sum must be made over all of the relativistic species at that temperature of the universe (we already discussed how the non-relativistic ones don't account for a big contribution).

My problem is that he quickly jumped to the next conclussion:

> Thus, we can relate the rate of expansion of the universe (and hence, the age of it) to the temperature of the relativistic plasma by $$H=1.66g_*\frac{1}{2} \frac{T^2}{M_P}=\frac{1}{2t}$$

But he didn't make the derivation of this explicit (I can't even find what $M_P$ is). Any light on this, blibliography or reference so I can do a bit of research on my own will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $M_P$ is surely the Planck mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the Friedmann equation with no curvature:
$$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho $$
Where $\rho$ is the energy density.
In early Universe the Universe is dominated by radiation and $\rho =\rho_r$

A know result is that $\rho_r \propto a^{-4}$ where a is the scale factor of the Universe.

And thus $$H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}=-\frac{\dot{\rho_r}}{4\rho_r} = \left(\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho_r\right)^{1/2}$$
So we can integrate and find that :
$$\rho_r = \frac{3}{32 \pi G}t^{-2} $$
So $$\frac{\dot{\rho_r}}{\rho_r} = -2t^{-1} $$
and $$H = -\frac{\dot{\rho_r}}{4\rho_r} = \frac{1}{2t} $$
The radiation energy density for a plasma of bosons and fermions is given by :
$$ \rho_r c^2 = \pi^4(k_B T)^4 \frac{g^*}{2}\frac{1}{15\pi^2\hbar^3c^3}$$
This results come from Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein statistic integrated over phase space.

Taking all these formulae together gives:
$$H = \left(\frac{4\pi^3 G g^*}{45\hbar^3c^5}\right)^{1/2} (kT)^2 =1.66 \frac{\sqrt{g^*}}{M_P \hbar c^2}(k_B T)^2 = \frac{1}{2t} $$
Where $M_P = \sqrt{\hbar c/G}$ is the Planck mass

Hope that is clear !

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!